# Difference Bertween wp_enqueue_script and wp_localize_script Need a Basic Example in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I need a Clear Explanation on wp_enqueue_script and wp_localize_script

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custome.js',PLUGIN_URL.'/js/custome.js');
     wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object',
     array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

Comment: In general, localization has to do with language translations. As for the difference, they are used for different things and cannot be compared.  There is a perfectly fine description of it on the wordpress website  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: In your example it creates a javascript object named `my_ajax_object` with the third argument as the data..  `alert(my_ajax_object.ajax_url)` which should alert the value of `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )`  in this case its being used to pass that data to javascript.  I haven't really used it, but according to the documentation that is what it should do...  You can do the same thing using php and echoing the json data to the page.  This lets you do it without editing any theme templates (I guess)

Answer (score 3):

**wp_enqueue_script** will include a Javascript file into your page or application. In Javascript file you may need to access few PHP variables or few Values that set from the your WordPress Pages. As example, when AJAX called in WordPress, it basically call a single URL that is "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", so you can access this URL from js file by hardcoding like :

```
var ajax_url="<site url>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
```

So if you moved the code into different domain, you need to change the code in ajavscript, which usually forgotten. The solution is to make this URL dynamic so it react same with any URL. The code :

```
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object',array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

is actually sending the AJAX URL using a variable named "**ajax_url**" with an object named "**my_ajax_object**". So you can access the AJAX URL in javascript file. Like :

```
var ajax_url=my_ajax_object.ajax_url;
```

Now if you need to send more values you can use same way :

```
 wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object',array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),'your_name'=>'Tristup' ) );
```

In Javascript File :

```
console.log(my_ajax_object.your_name);
```

Hope it help you to understand the localized script, if any doubts please reply to this.